# Laravel, testing route middleware returning true

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-6

I've been writing a few tests to check on the middlewares that are applied to certain routes.
I've got Gate's defined in order to use them as role validations.

My routes are defined as such:

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index')->middleware(['can:Administrator'])->name('user.index');
```

On my route service provider, I've defined that this route file uses another middleware aswell, called `api`.

In my unit test, I fetch the route by the name and compare the middlewares it should be applied, as such

```
public function testMiddlewaresAssignedToUserIndex() {
  $expectedMiddlewares = ['api', 'can:Administrator'];
  $this->assertEquals($expectedMiddlewares, Route::getRoutes()->getByName('user.index')->gatherMiddleware());
}
```

This works as intended. However, when required to apply more than one condition such as "Administrator or Supervisor", it returns true. In order to validate either one of those roles, the route is written as such:

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index')->middleware(['can:Administrator' ||'can:Supervisor'])->name('user.index');
```

What happens now is that in the test, it returns `['api', true]`. This won't let me test that those 2 gates are applied as middlewares to the route.

What other approach or how can I test the route's middlewares?

Comment: `['can:Administrator' ||'can:Supervisor']` is not a valid way to do this. I think you should define a policy like `AdministratorOrSupervisor` and use `can:AdministratorOrSupervisor`  . `['can:Administrator' ||'can:Supervisor']` just does an `OR` between two truthy strings so will return a boolean true (which is what you are seeing in your test)

Comment: but that would imply that I would need to make multiple role combinations, imagine scaling them

Comment: Yes this is a known limitation